# Collab with SIM800C integrating

Tags: command, decoding, gsm

I am fairly new to coding. However I have a software on my computer and I am looking to figure out how to connect my SIM800C to the Bluetooth on my Software on my labtop. Would I need a sim still? As the program I am trying to connect it to doesn’t need Wi-Fi. Please let me know , or anyone looking to collab on this  please let me know

I have tried a few things but I am still pretty new to coding. I am self taught. I can catch on fast.